# brew changes from php71 to php@7.1 on installation

Tags: install, homebrew, php

I am trying to install php71 with the command `brew install php71` but instead `php@7.1` is installed.

When trying to install redis with `brew install php71-redis` it's installing but not working with that `php@7.1`.

macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

also sometimes still get this warning:
`Warning: Use php@7.1 instead of deprecated homebrew/php/php71`

Comment: What exactly is ‘not working’ with installing redis? Do you get an error message? ‘php@7.1’ is the canonical name for PHP at version 7.1, this is expected and correct.

Comment: usually I have php71 folder in `/usr/local/opt/` and i was having also php71-redis and so on.. now i have php@7.1 folder and php71-redis and redis is not runing.. on this php@7.1 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer!
After this update (brew) we need to install pear (pecl) for installing extensions for php.. so i.e. redis extension was installed pretty easy like `pecl install redis` 
But need to be set correct php version that pear (pecl) would found where to install extension.